# Preselect tab in TabLayout with ViewPager2

Tags: kotlin

I have a `ViewPager2` and a `TabLayout` that contains two tabs.
How do I select second tab when first entering the page?

EDIT:
I managed to select second tab like so: `tabLayout.getTabAt(1).select()`
But I have another problem now, because the page under it is the page that corresponds to the first tab and `viewPager.setCurrentItem(1, true)` doesn't seem to fix it.

Comment: Did you try `viewPager.setCurrentItem(1)`?

Comment: See my edit please.

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60933258/13308991) answer fixes your issue.

Comment: I tried using `tabLayout.post {  tabLayout.getTabAt(1).select() }`, because with view pager was not working, but now I see the first tab being selected and than right after the second tab.

Comment: You mean your are able to see the transition from one page to another? And you want to directly show the second page with no transition?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I want the second page to appear directly.

Comment: `viewPager.setCurrentItem(1, true)` Pass `false` instead of `true`. This boolean is for `smoothScroll` which we don't want here.

Comment: Thank you so much! That was the issue, is working now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use,

```kotlin
viewPager.post {
  viewPager.setCurrentItem(1, false)
}
```

Pass `false` to directly jump to second page instead of a smooth scroll.